# Convergence in probability of a random variable that takes $0$ with probability $1/2 + 1/(n+1)$ and $1$ otherwise.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be a  sequence of random variables such that 
$P(X_n = 0) = 1/2 + 1/(n+1)$ and $P(X_n=1) = 1/2 - 1/(n+1)$. Then does $X_n$ converge in probability?

I know that $X_n$ converges in distribution to a random variable $X$ with distribution $P(X=0) = 1/2$ and $P(X=1) = 1/2$. But I don't know how to show convergence in proability for this random variable. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this all you know about the sequence? No independence or something like that?

Comment: The way this is stated, you cannot determine if $X_n\to X$ in probabililty.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Yes this is all I have.

Comment: @AdamMartens Why not?

Comment: If $n$ is even, consider $X_n:=1_{[0,1/2+1/(n+1)]}$ and if $n$ is odd, consider, $X_n:=1_{[1/2-1/(n+1),1]}$. Here, the probability space is $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure

Comment: @AdamMartens Something, something great minds. :P

Comment: Exact same time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It need not... you need to know something about the coupling of the $X_n$. Say your probability space is $([0,1],\mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ with the latter denoting the Borel algebra and Lesbegue measure respectively. Let $X_n=1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}]}$ for $n$ odd and $X_n=1_{[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1},1]}$ for $n$ even. Then, $X_n$ does not converge in probability.

Indeed, if it did converge, it would be Cauchy in Probability, but $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X_{n+1}|\geq 1)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for any $n$.

Comment: I don't understand why $X_n = 1_{[0,1/2 + 1/(n+1)]}$ for $n$ odd. That means $P(X_n = 1) = 1/2 + 1/(n+1)$.

Comment: Whoops, other way around. Just change the signs to get the proper probabilities.